# Help With Zend_Db_Stmt

Tags: zend-framework, pdo, zend-db

I have a little problem with the Zend_Db_Stmt. This works:

```
    $sql = " SELECT * FROM bugs";
    $stmt = $this->_getDb()->query($sql);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

But I am trying to make sure the PDO gets used to query the database so I tried this:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bugs";        
    $stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo($this->_getDb(), $sql);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

And this doesn't work (it returns an empty array). Could you please help me figure this out? The above code works if I use execute() method for UPDATE or INSERT queries but fetchAll() doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to execute!

```
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

See more examples in [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).